# How to find $du$ where $u=f(t,t^2,t^3)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find $du$ if $u=f(x,y,z)$, $x=t$, $y=t^2$, and $z=t^3$. So this means that I have to find $du$ where $u=f(t,t^2,t^3)$. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align*}
u &= f(x,y,z)\\
x &= t \\
y &= t^2 \\
z &= t^3 \\
du &= f_x dx+f_ydy+f_zdz \\
dx &= x_t dt = dt \\
dy &= y_t dt  = 2tdt\\
dz &= z_t dt = 3t^2 dt \\
du &= \left( f_x + 2tf_y + 3t^2 f_z\right)dt
\end{align*}
$$